# AWS Amplify post request fails with "status code 403 at node_modules/axios"

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, aws-amplify

I configured and initialized AWS Amplify for my ReactNative/Expo app and added a REST Api. Im new to AWS in general, but im assuming that once I add the API, my project is populated with `amplify/backend` folders and files and is ready for consumption.

So i tried to create a simple `post` request to create an item in my DynamoDB table with

```
import { Amplify, API } from "aws-amplify";
import awsconfig from "./src/aws-exports";

Amplify.configure(awsconfig);

const enterData = async () => {
  API.post("API", "/", {
    body: {
      dateID: "testing",
    },
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${(await Auth.currentSession())
        .getIdToken()
        .getJwtToken()}`
    }
  })
    .then((result) => {
      // console.log(JSON.parse(result));
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};

const signIn = async () => {
  Auth.signIn('test@test.com', 'testpassword')
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data)
    enterData() //enterData is attempted after signin is confirmed. 
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
  })
}

signIn()
```

I did not touch anything else in my project folder besides including the above in my `App.tsx` because im unsure if i need to and where. I got a 403 error code and it "points" to the `axios` package but im not sure if issue is related to aws integration.

I configured the REST Api with restricted access where Authenticated users are allowed to *CRUD*, and guests are allowed to *Read*. How could I even check if I am considered an "Authorized User" .

Comment: unsure why, but removing the authorization header make it work. I am now able to perform api requests without 403 error.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  AWS Amplify API category uses Axios under the hood so axios is related to your problem.

Probably you get 403 because you didn't authorized, for Rest API's you need to set authorization headers,

I don't know how is your config but you can take help from this page. Please review the "Define Authorization Rules" section under the API(REST) section.

https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/restapi/authz/q/platform/js/#customizing-http-request-headers

To check authorization methods, you can use "Auth" class like that also you can see auth class usage in the above link.

```
import { Amplify, API, Auth } from "aws-amplify";
```

https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-js/api/classes/authclass.html

Comment: ive updated my code to reflect my authorization attempt through cognito. but i still get 403 error.

Comment: Can you edit the question with your relevant codebase, how did you try to implement ?